# How to Format Python code as Python snippets on stack overflow?

Tags: python, code-snippets

How to format Python code as Python snippets on stack overflow since we can only do it as JavaScript or HTML or CSS snippets?

Comment: This is probably a question for [meta]

Comment: I would imagine that JS, HTML, and CSS are supported as actual snippets because SO is used on a browser, and those are browser-specific languages. There is no expectation that someone would be able to run Python in a browser so the code cannot be executed in a snippet and instead, you're expected to simply format Python code as "code".

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking?  Are you asking about properly formatting (highlighting, etc.) posted Python code or about making it executable?  "format Python code" and "Python snippets" are two different things, as snippets are about making code executable.

Comment: @Python_Guy As others have correctly pointed out, only HTML/JS/CSS are supported. However, using [pyodide](https://pyodide.org/en/stable/) you can run python in the browser and call it from JS. Using this, my project [PyPrez](https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/) allows you to run Python snippets in your Stack Overflow questions and answers

Answer (score 3):

If you mean **executable** snippets, you can only do this with `html`/`css`/`js`:

```css
p {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>You can't do this with Python... sadly</p>
```

If you want to simply format a snippet, you can do this:

```
# This is Python code
```

printing this:

````
```python
# This is Python code
```
````

to do this you have to send key `ctrl+k` on a new line.